# Delphi. Flickering of MainMenu with icons and Controls on GroupBox, which is on PageControl

Tags: delphi, menu, controls, delphi-2010, flicker

1. I have Main Menu and icons in it and Menu flickers, but a menu without icons does not flicker! Delphi2010 has icons in Menu too, but Menu does not flicker.
2. I have Labels on GroupBox, this GroupBox is on a PageControl (anchors are set). If I try to resize a form in this condition I get unbelievable, terrible flickering! DoubleBuffered does not help.

Comment: What is a `PagePanel`? Anyhow, you need to be psychic in order to solve this without any real details...

Comment: I am sorry, PageControl!

Comment: For item 2, the only thing I have found to work is to set the WS_EX_COMPOSITED window style on the group box (and radio groups) whilst in a sizing loop. I've never seen flickering on a menu.

Comment: I just created empty project, created MAIN Menu and put some icons. There is flicker but little bit - of background. I can see it, it is not big flickering but it exist. I have Delphi 2010

Comment: How did you put the icons in the menu? Did you put them straight into the bitmap property of the menu items or did you add the icons to an imagelist and set the imagelist property of the menu and the imageindex property for each menu item?

Comment: Create a DFM that exhibits this behaviour and post it here (or somewhere else and provide the link).

Comment: 1) I have never seen this, the only thing that came to my mind is that you have icons larger than the items itself 2) I've had the same problem in D2009, where I'm using [VCLFixPack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/vclfixpack-10/) to solve [this issue](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=56252), but I hope it's fixed in D2010.

Comment: You should separate the questions, the second about resize flicker is similar to mine here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031147/how-can-i-reduce-pagecontrol-flicker-in-delphi

Comment: @mjn - But it was in D2009; wasn't that fixed in D2010 ?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting ParentBackground to False for components on the PageControl, this helped me here: [How can I reduce PageControl flicker in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031147/how-can-i-reduce-pagecontrol-flicker-in-delphi)

Answer (score 0):

You can set doublebuffered property of page control to true. this will do the painting of controls move faster