# TLabel and TGroupbox Captions Flicker on Resize

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, flicker, groupbox, tpagecontrol

- So, I have an application that loads different plugins and creates a
  new tab on a TPageControl for each one.
- Each DLL has a TForm associated with it.
- The forms are created with their parent hWnd as the new TTabSheet.
- Since the TTabSheets aren't a parent of the form as far as VCL is concerned (*didn't want to use dynamic RTL, and plugins made in other languages*) I have to handle resizes manually. I do this like below:

  ```
  var
    ChildHandle : DWORD;
  begin
    If Assigned(pcMain.ActivePage) Then
      begin
      ChildHandle := FindWindowEx(pcMain.ActivePage.Handle, 0, 'TfrmPluginForm', nil);
      If ChildHandle > 0 Then
        begin
        SetWindowPos(ChildHandle, 0, 0, 0, pcMain.ActivePage.Width, pcMain.ActivePage.Height, SWP_NOZORDER + SWP_NOACTIVATE + SWP_NOCOPYBITS);
      end;
    end;
  ```

Now, my problem is that when the application is resized, all the TGroupBoxes and the TLabels inside the TGroupBoxes flicker. The TLabels that are not inside TGroupboxes are fine and don't flicker.

**Things I've tried:**

- WM_SETREDRAW followed by a RedrawWindow
- ParentBackground on the TGroupBoxes and TLabels set to False
- DoubleBuffer := True
- LockWindowUpdate (*Yes, even though I know it's very very wrong*)
- Transparent := False (*even overriding create to edit ControlState*)

**Any ideas?**

Comment: This question has a few additional ideas in answers and comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031147

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The only thing I have found to work well is to use the `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` window style.  This is a performance hog so I only enable it when in a sizing loop. It is my experience that, with the built-in controls, in my app, flickering only occurs when resizing forms.

You should first perform a quick test to see if this approach will help you by simply adding the `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` window style to all your windowed controls. If that works you can consider the more advanced approach below:

**Quick hack**

```
procedure EnableComposited(WinControl: TWinControl);
var
  i: Integer;
  NewExStyle: DWORD;
begin
  NewExStyle := GetWindowLong(WinControl.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
  SetWindowLong(WinControl.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, NewExStyle);

  for i := 0 to WinControl.ControlCount-1 do
    if WinControl.Controls[i] is TWinControl then
      EnableComposited(TWinControl(WinControl.Controls[i]));
end;
```

Call this, for example, in the `OnShow` for your `TForm`, passing the form instance. If that helps then you really should implement it more discerningly. I give you the relevant extracts from my code to illustrate how I did that.

**Full code**

```
procedure TMyForm.WMEnterSizeMove(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  BeginSizing;
end;

procedure TMyForm.WMExitSizeMove(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  EndSizing;
  inherited;
end;

procedure SetComposited(WinControl: TWinControl; Value: Boolean);
var
  ExStyle, NewExStyle: DWORD;
begin
  ExStyle := GetWindowLong(WinControl.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
  if Value then begin
    NewExStyle := ExStyle or WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
  end else begin
    NewExStyle := ExStyle and not WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
  end;
  if NewExStyle<>ExStyle then begin
    SetWindowLong(WinControl.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, NewExStyle);
  end;
end;

function TMyForm.SizingCompositionIsPerformed: Boolean;
begin
  //see The Old New Thing, Taxes: Remote Desktop Connection and painting
  Result := not InRemoteSession;
end;
procedure TMyForm.BeginSizing;
var
  UseCompositedWindowStyleExclusively: Boolean;
  Control: TControl;
  WinControl: TWinControl;
begin
  if SizingCompositionIsPerformed then begin
    UseCompositedWindowStyleExclusively := Win32MajorVersion>=6;//XP can't handle too many windows with WS_EX_COMPOSITED
    for Control in ControlEnumerator(TWinControl) do begin
      WinControl := TWinControl(Control);
      if UseCompositedWindowStyleExclusively then begin
        SetComposited(WinControl, True);
      end else begin
        if WinControl is TPanel then begin
          TPanel(WinControl).FullRepaint := False;
        end;
        if (WinControl is TCustomGroupBox) or (WinControl is TCustomRadioGroup) or (WinControl is TCustomGrid) then begin
          //can't find another way to make these awkward customers stop flickering
          SetComposited(WinControl, True);
        end else if ControlSupportsDoubleBuffered(WinControl) then begin
          WinControl.DoubleBuffered := True;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.EndSizing;
var
  Control: TControl;
  WinControl: TWinControl;
begin
  if SizingCompositionIsPerformed then begin
    for Control in ControlEnumerator(TWinControl) do begin
      WinControl := TWinControl(Control);
      if WinControl is TPanel then begin
        TPanel(WinControl).FullRepaint := True;
      end;
      UpdateDoubleBuffered(WinControl);
      SetComposited(WinControl, False);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TMyForm.ControlSupportsDoubleBuffered(Control: TWinControl): Boolean;
const
  NotSupportedClasses: array [0..1] of TControlClass = (
    TCustomForm,//general policy is not to double buffer forms
    TCustomRichEdit//simply fails to draw if double buffered
  );
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := low(NotSupportedClasses) to high(NotSupportedClasses) do begin
    if Control is NotSupportedClasses[i] then begin
      Result := False;
      exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

procedure TMyForm.UpdateDoubleBuffered(Control: TWinControl);

  function ControlIsDoubleBuffered: Boolean;
  const
    DoubleBufferedClasses: array [0..2] of TControlClass = (
      TMyCustomGrid,//flickers when updating
      TCustomListView,//flickers when updating
      TCustomStatusBar//drawing infidelities , e.g. my main form status bar during file loading
    );
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    if not InRemoteSession then begin
      //see The Old New Thing, Taxes: Remote Desktop Connection and painting
      for i := low(DoubleBufferedClasses) to high(DoubleBufferedClasses) do begin
        if Control is DoubleBufferedClasses[i] then begin
          Result := True;
          exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    Result := False;
  end;

var
  DoubleBuffered: Boolean;

begin
  if ControlSupportsDoubleBuffered(Control) then begin
    DoubleBuffered := ControlIsDoubleBuffered;
  end else begin
    DoubleBuffered := False;
  end;
  Control.DoubleBuffered := DoubleBuffered;
end;

procedure TMyForm.UpdateDoubleBuffered;
var
  Control: TControl;
begin
  for Control in ControlEnumerator(TWinControl) do begin
    UpdateDoubleBuffered(TWinControl(Control));
  end;
end;
```

This won't compile for you, but it should contain some useful ideas. `ControlEnumerator` is my utility to turn a recursive walk of the child controls into a flat `for` loop. Note that I also use a custom splitter that calls BeginSizing/EndSizing when it is active.

Another useful trick is to use `TStaticText` instead of `TLabel` which you occasionally need to do when you have deep nesting of page controls and panels.

I've used this code to make my app 100% flicker free but it took me ages and ages of experimenting to get it all in place.  Hopefully others can find something of use in here.

Comment: +1, TStaticText saves your day when using panels and page controls instead of TLabel.

Comment: Oh yes, I most certainly can find something useful in here :-) Thanks and +1

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not function when Aero visual interface is enabled in Window Vista and later OS.

Comment: @truthseeker Nope. Works fine on all Windows versions. Did you note the behaviour switch in the code? XP is a special case.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [VCL Fix Pack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/vclfixpack-10/) from [Andreas Hausladen](http://andy.jgknet.de/).

Additionally: do not specify the `SWP_NOCOPYBITS` flag, and set `DoubleBuffered` of the PageControl:

```
uses
  VCLFixPack;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PageControl1.DoubleBuffered := True;

  //Setup test conditions:
  FForm2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
  FForm2.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  FForm2.BoundsRect := TabSheet1.ClientRect;
  Windows.SetParent(FForm2.Handle, TabSheet1.Handle);
  FForm2.Show;
  PageControl1.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
  PageControl1.OnResize := PageControl1Resize;
end;

procedure TForm1.PageControl1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetWindowPos(FForm2.Handle, 0, 0, 0, TabSheet1.ClientWidth,
    TabSheet1.ClientHeight, SWP_NOZORDER + SWP_NOACTIVATE);
end;
```

Comment: I haven't heard of the VCL Fix Pack, I will try it out.

Comment: Does not apply to d2010

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I use with success in my project for a number of forms. It's a little bit dirty because it uses WinAPI functions. In comparison with David answer, it doesn't involve a performance penalty. The point is to overwrite the message handler for `WM_ERASEBKGND` messages for the form and all of its child windows, preventing repeated drawing to the same area, which causes flicker.

```c++
typedef LRESULT CALLBACK(*PWndProc)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void SetNonFlickeringWndProc(TWinControl &control, std::map<HWND,PWndProc> &list, PWndProc new_proc)
{
   if (control.Handle == 0)
   {
      return;
   }

   PWndProc oldWndProc = (PWndProc)SetWindowLong(control.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)new_proc);
   list[control.Handle] = oldWndProc;

   int count = control.ControlCount;
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
      TControl *child_control = control.Controls[i];
      TWinControl *child_wnd_control = dynamic_cast<TWinControl*>(child_control);
      if (child_wnd_control == NULL)
      {
         continue;
      }

      SetNonFlickeringWndProc(*child_wnd_control, list, new_proc);
   }
}

void RestoreWndProc(std::map<HWND,PWndProc> &old_wnd_proc)
{
   std::map<HWND,PWndProc>::iterator it;
   for (it = old_wnd_proc.begin(); it != old_wnd_proc.end(); it++)
   {
      LONG res = SetWindowLong(it->first, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)it->second);
   }
   old_wnd_proc.clear();
}

std::map<HWND,PWndProc> oldwndproc;   // addresses for window procedures for all components in form

LRESULT CALLBACK NonFlickeringWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_ERASEBKGND)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return ((PWndProc)oldwndproc[hwnd])(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
   oldwndproc.clear();
   SetNonFlickeringWndProc(*this, oldwndproc, &NonFlickeringWndProc);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::FormClose(TObject* Sender, TCloseAction& Action)
{
   RestoreWndProc(oldwndproc_etype);
}
```

Important note: The form's `DoubleBuffered` property must be set on if you don't want to see black stripes on the sides!

Answer (score 1):

Put above your form (**interface**) or put it all in a new last unit to include:

```
TLabel = class( stdCtrls.TLabel )
  protected
   procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWmEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  end;
```

Put this in **implementation** part

```
procedure TLabel.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWmEraseBkgnd);
begin
 Message.Result:=1; // Fake erase
end;
```

repeat this step for TGroupBox

Comment: To avoid flickering on TGroupbox i set it's 'ParentBackground' property to false and 'DoubleBuffer' prop to true.

Comment: 'repeat this step for TGroupBox', is in the answer,