# Adding non-VCL window into VCL align queue

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-xe, vcl

Some background (*kind of a continuation of [TLabel and TGroupbox Captions Flicker on Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058745/tlabel-and-tgroupbox-captions-flicker-on-resize)*):

- So, I have an application that loads different plugins and creates a
  new tab on a TPageControl for each one.
- Each DLL has a TForm associated with it.
- The forms are created with their parent hWnd as the new TTabSheet.
  Since the TTabSheets aren't a parent of the form as far as VCL is
  concerned (*didn't want to use dynamic RTL, and    plugins made in
  other languages*) I have to handle resizes manually.

I just seem to be running into a lot of new issues (*but great learning experiences*) for this "plugin" type of application.

So, my current struggle is trying to have a plugin that doesn't get inserted into a TTabSheet but will be resized and aligned directly on the form.

Since this would be easier to explain with a picture:
[image: Visual representation of question]
Now I **could** manually do the alignment and the resize, but I'd much rather have the VCL alignment procedures (*alClient, alTop, etc*) do it for me. That way I would just have to set the plugins alignment on its form without thinking.

After looking through the VCL source I began to step through the align code and how it's called. Basically when a TControl gets a WM_RESIZE it will:

1. Call Realign() which calls AlignControl()
2. AlignControl() will get the client rect and call AlignControls()
3. AlignControls() will call DoAlign() for each TAlignment type in this order: alTop, alBottom, alLeft, alRight, alClient, alCustom, alNone
4. DoAlign() will loop through FControls and FWinControls (*which are TLists*) and will align them appropriately

So my thought process is that if I create a new TWinControl, set it's handle to the plugins form (*window*) handle, and insert it into the FControls list with the proper align it should do my work for me.

Of course I'm here, so it failed miserably. I even get an AV when exiting the application about an invalid window handle. My guess is that the TWinControl I created is trying to free the handle of the plugins form (*window*) which doesn't exist any more.

What I've tried:

```
procedure AddHandleToControlList(AHandle: DWORD; Align: TAlign);
var
  NewWinControl : TWinControl;
begin
  NewWinControl := TWinControl.Create(frmMain);
  NewWinControl.WindowHandle := AHandle;
  NewWinControl.Align := Align;
  NewWinControl.Width := frmMain.ClientWidth;
  NewWinControl.Height := 30;
  NewWinControl.Parent := frmMain;
end;

procedure AddHandleToControlList(AHandle: DWORD; Align: TAlign);
var
  NewWinControl : TWinControl;
begin
  NewWinControl := TWinControl.Create(frmMain);
  NewWinControl.WindowHandle := AHandle;
  NewWinControl.Align := Align;
  NewWinControl.Width := frmMain.ClientWidth;
  NewWinControl.Height := 30;
  TWinControl(frmMain).Insert(NewWinControl);
end;
```

Soooo, thoughts?

**EDIT 1:**

Ok, so this correctly adds the control to the list and conforms the the TAlign set (why is it that I spend 8 hours trying to figure something out, I post here, and then the answer just appears...oh well someone might find this question and my ramblings useful):

```
procedure AddHandleToControlList(AHandle: DWORD; AName: PChar; ATop, ALeft, AWidth, AHeight: Integer; AAlign: TAlign);
var
  NewWinControl : TWinControl;
begin
  NewWinControl := TWinControl.Create(frmMain);
  With NewWinControl Do
    begin
    Name := AName;
    Top := ATop;
    Left := ALeft;
    Width := AWidth;
    Height := AHeight;
    Align := AAlign;
    WindowHandle := AHandle;
    Visible := True;
  end;
  TWinControl(frmMain).InsertControl(NewWinControl);
end;
```

The issue now is that when the application closes, I get the invalid error AV...I shall continue!!

**EDIT 2:**
Ok, so it is TWinControl.DestroyWindowHandle that raises the AV because the window handle doesn't exist any more. I'm trying to think of a clean solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Derive a new class from `TWinControl` and override its virtual `DestroyWindowHandle()` method to not free the `HWND` you provide. The default implementation of `TWinControl.DestroyWindowHandle()` calls the Win32 API `DestroyWnd()` function.

Comment: That's a much more elegant solution than what I was doing! Perfect, thank you!

Comment: +1 Wow. I'm in doubt about whether to call this a hack or a trick, but hell, giving a random windowed control VCL characteristics sure is usefull! Thanks. You both!

Comment: It is not a hack. TWinControl's `CreateWindowHandle()` and `DestroyWindowHandle()` methods are intentionally virtual to allow for custom window management.