# Doublebuffering form causes black dots at corners of text box

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, doublebuffered

When I have a few text boxes on a form and set the `DoubleBuffered` property of the form to `True`, it makes the text boxes on the form have black dots at each of the corners. Here's what the corners of the text boxes look like **without** `DoubleBuffered` on their parent form:

[image]

And here's what they look like **with** `DoubleBuffered`:

[image]

I have already tried setting `DoubleBuffered` to `False` on the text boxes themselves, but that doesn't help at all. What can I do to fix this annoyance?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove DoubleBuffering on the components that do this.

The Form will still be Double Buffered, and the Edit boxes won't show the black corners.

Either from the Object Inspector, or by code:

```
Form1.DoubleBuffered := True;
Edit1.DoubleBuffered := False;
Edit2.DoubleBuffered := False;
```

Comment: Actually the black dots still show up even when the textboxes themselves are not double buffered.

Comment: Yeah I just tried that, sorry I thought it might of worked, I don't understand why that wouldn't work.

Comment: DoubleBuffering always seems odd to me, TToolBar goes crazy with DoubleBuffering unless DrawingStyle is set to Gradient.

Comment: That's just what happens and is why I never use double buffering

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am performing a lot of updates on a control though and it flickers badly if not double buffered.

Comment: @Seth I typically have problems with flicker when resizing. I deal with them as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060672  Perhaps you can find something of use there