# TToolbar incompatible with TForm.DoubleBuffered?

Tags: delphi, toolbar, vcl, delphi-xe3, doublebuffered

I am using Delphi XE3.
When I create a new VCL project and drop a `TToolbar` on it, everything works fine - except when I activate `Form1.DoubleBuffered`.
From that moment on, drawing of the toolbar is broken - in designtime, it's either black, transparent, or parts of the IDE (statusbar, toolbar, etc.) are copied into it. It changes between these options when I click on it and when I change to source code (F12) and back.
In runtime, it's always black.

With `DrawingStyle=dsGradient`, everything works as expected. Switching back to `dsNormal` breaks it again.

Deactivating `Form1.DoubleBuffered` repairs it.

Any hints how to work around that issue?

Comment: See [`When not to use DoubleBuffered`](http://chee-yang.blogspot.se/2010/02/when-not-to-use-doublebuffered.html). Workaround here is to put the `TToolBar` on a `TPanel`.

Comment: Thank you LU RD - works perfectly. If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Or you might fill the toolbar's client rectangle in the `OnAdvancedCustomDraw` event at the `cdPrePaint` drawing stage (quite a [`dirty workaround`](http://pastebin.com/b9yXE5Su) though).

Comment: Thank you for that link, David. I don't need `DoubleBuffered` for deflickering VCL components, but for a `TPaintBox` that is drawing a chart (with user interaction like zooming and dragging). I know I could use a `TBitmap` (or a `TImage`), but as long `Form.Doublebuffered` works (and no other problems arise), I prefer the single click solution.

Comment: Doublebuffered creates lots of problems in many controls not only with TToolbar. But if you disable it you will have a lot of flicker in some areas of your program... So... choose your poison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion the solution is to set `TForm.DoubleBuffered` to `False`. Using a value of `True` causes all sorts of other problems. This property worked reasonably well before XP themes, but since their arrival, using `TForm.DoubleBuffered` has not been viable, in my view.

In addition to the problems you have encountered, I've come across lots of painting flaws when using the Windows Basic theme. I know that's not mainstream, but I happen to see that a lot with remote access. And there's more. When you double buffer a form you stop the theme animation from working. For example, a default button pulses to indicate that it is the default button.

If you get resize flickering without double buffering the form, use the [ideas from my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058745/tlabel-and-tgroupbox-captions-flicker-on-resize#8060672). From the comments it seems that the flickering you wish to combat is in a paint box. I obviously don't know the details, but my experience and instincts say that you should be able to deal quite easily with that flickering at a local level. There surely should be no need for the global form wide double buffering.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. As I posted to your comment on my question, I'll use the `TPanel` solution for now - but I'll keep your remarks in mind and will definitely look into the issues you mentioned; problably I'll do what you said. Thanks again.

Comment: De-flickering your paint box is very easy. Double buffering the form is grossly over the top. It influences so much else. It's a global solution to a local problem. It should be avoided.

Comment: Yes, I can't negate what you say. I didn't know `TForm.DoubleBuffered` causes that much problems; I think I'll go and deactivate it everywhere I've used it until now. So thank you once again ;)

Answer (score 4):

As reported in this article, [`When not to use DoubleBuffered`](http://chee-yang.blogspot.se/2010/02/when-not-to-use-doublebuffered.html), some controls like `TToolBar` and `TRichEdit` don't work well with the `DoubleBuffered` property set to true.

The reason be be found in documentation, [`TWinControl.DoubleBuffered`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DoubleBuffered), where some WinControls can't draw themselves on a temporary bitmap (as happens when `DoubleBuffered` is true).

One workaround can be to put the `TToolBar` on a `TPanel`.