# Delphi TSplitter flickering issue

Tags: delphi, flicker, vcl-styles

I am using Delphi with VCL styles enabled and I would like to change the color of the TSplitter for my form.  I override `TSplitter.Paint` in an interposer class to paint a darker color than the default VCL styles `cBtnFace` color, but there is significant flickering on the form when resized.  Is there a way to remove this flickering?

I've tried these things to try and reduce the flickering, but none have worked:

1. Disabling VCL styles (`TSplitter.StyleElements := []`).
2. Changing the VCL Styles Bitmap Style Designer's object element for "Splitter," but modifying this object element doesn't change the splitter's appearance.
3. Trying to process the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message on `TControl` objects, but I was unable to get the procedure to be called in my interposer class.

   ```
   procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Msg: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
   ...
   procedure TSplitter.WMEraseBkgnd(var Msg: TWMEraseBkgnd);
   begin
       // this is never invoked by the TSplitter
       Msg.Result := 1;
   end;
   ```

Any other ideas for getting rid of the flickering on a `TSplitter`?  There's no DoubleBuffer  property for `TSplitter` or anything like that from what I can tell.

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, I can't share the codebase, but I can tell you that this is the way the application UI is setup when the `TSplitter` flickers:

```
TForm (DoubleBuffered = False)
-> BackgroundPanel (DoubleBuffered = True, ParentBackground = False)
-> -> A TGradient, image and label to fill the BackgroundPanel
-> LeftPanel (ParentBackground = False`, no flickering)
-> -> LeftPanelFrame and frame content (selective double buffering)
-> TSplitter
-> RightPanel (ParentBackground = False, no flickering)
-> -> RightPanelFrame and frame content (selective double buffering)
```

There is also a toolbar and a main menu at the top of the form, but the rest of the UI components are set to alClient (or OnResized to fill the space).

I assumed that since the BackgroundPanel is behind the LeftPanel, `TSplitter`, and RightPanel (i.e, Control -> Send to Back), the `DoubleBuffered = True` and `ParentBackground = False` on the BackgroundPanel would help reduce/remove the flicker from any components on an immediate UI layer in front of it (i.e, the `TSplitter`).  But, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Perhaps I'll try placing a `TPanel` as a parent of LeftPanel, `TSplitter`, and RightPanel and set its `DoubleBuffered = True` and `ParentBackground = False`.  I'll have to try that later and get back.  So, it would look like this:

```
TForm
-> BackgroundPanel (DoubleBuffered = True, ParentBackground = False)
-> -> A TGradient, image and label to fill the BackgroundPanel
-> EncapsulatingPanel (DoubleBuffered = True, ParentBackground = False)
-> -> LeftPanel (ParentBackground = False)
-> -> -> LeftPanelFrame and frame content
-> -> TSplitter
-> -> RightPanel (ParentBackground = False)
-> -> -> RightPanelFrame and frame content
```

Lastly, I should note that double buffering the TForm substantially slows down the UI when resizing (a black trail on the right of the window), not when doing other UI things when the app is not resizing.

**UPDATE 2**

Unfortunately, while my approach above (creating a background parent `TPanel`) fixed the flickering on the `TSplitter`, it also caused other weird UI issues, perhaps some of which @David Heffernan alluded to in the comments.  For now, I've just left the flickering issue, since the splitter is only 1px wide and only flickers on width + height resizing.

Comment: I'm still waiting for the `TFlickerFreeForm` or `TFlickerFreeControl` to be introduced.

Comment: Far fetched and sometimes insufficient solution, but have you tried enabling `DoubleBuffered`?

Comment: @JerryDodge There's no DoubleBuffered property on `TSplitter` if that's what you mean (bottom of my question).  I've tried enabling `DoubleBuffered` on parent UI objects to no avail.

Comment: No I mean on your form, and I missed that last part

Comment: @JerryDodge Wow, ok...  That actually fixed the flickering--turning on `DoubleBuffered` on the topmost form of my application (I have intermediate frames and panels).  It slows down my whole UI substantially though, so I'll have to find a more efficient way if one exists.  I guess I'll chalk this one up as my problem, something I should have tried earlier.  Thanks for the help.  If you post an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Can you post the code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: DoubleBuffered on a form breaks loads of other things. Best only to enable it when sizing. Better to avoid it by other means. My answer on the subject is a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058745/tlabel-and-tgroupbox-captions-flicker-on-resize

Comment: @RRUZ It sounds like there's far too much code to post here - the issue seems to be the fact that there are many controls and a lot of things going on.

Comment: See my answer (and edits) below, I'm also suggesting that while resizing, you can temporarily disable or pause program execution, any GUI updates, or otherwise anything that redraws.

Comment: @Jerry pause program execution? It's a sizing loop. Like a modal loop.

Comment: I didn't mean stop the message queue, I meant whatever logic is behind the program which might cause GUI updates.

Comment: That logic can't run in a sizing loop. Sizing loops just do sizing.

Comment: For anyone who cares, I added updates to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TSplitter` control may not have a `DoubleBuffered` property, but this property should be implemented on the upper-most control of where you experience flicker - in most cases, the form. As long as all the controls have `ParentDoubleBuffered` still enabled as default, they will all also acquire this change.

`DoubleBuffered` doesn't always fix flicker, and in some situations can make things worse. You may consider only using `DoubleBuffered` during resizing, and then switch it back off when resizing is done. This property should only be used on those controls which are actually being resized. For example, when resizing the form, enable `DoubleBuffered` on the form. But when resizing just the contents of a panel, enable it just for that panel (and all its child controls).

As for the performance drop of your application due to this change, you may also consider implementing a flag when you're resizing which will pause any program execution which might bog it down (anything that redraws such as labels, images, etc.). This its self may also be the solution to your problem as well (actually could be a second answer).