# Delphi: flickering on resize/maximize

Tags: delphi, mdichild

I'm developing a MDI application in Delphi XE5. i'm facing the common flickering problem when a child form is opened maximized, maximized, and resized.

I have solved the first issue usign [this trick](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2009/qt/delphi-mdi-child-prevent-on-create-resize-animation.htm). It works quite good (but not perfectly).
Now I'm not able to find a proper solution for stopping flickering when opened child form is maximized or resized. In particular, the flickering effect is very pronounced on the grids with propery `align = alClient`.

Have you got any suggestions for solving that? Thank you.

Comment: Have you found my answer to another SO question yet? WM_SETREDRAW is not what you need, FWIW.

Comment: Did you also set the DoubleBuffered of the form or panel to True?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058745/tlabel-and-tgroupbox-captions-flicker-on-resize