# Flickering when TPageControl has many tabs

Tags: delphi, controls, flicker, delphi-10-seattle, tpagecontrol

My problem is that I have a `TPageControl` which contains a dynamically created number of tabs each containing a single (`alClient`) `TMemo`. When this number of tabs exceeds the width of the control and the scroll arrows appear on the tab header, all (well a large number) of my controls start to flicker a lot. This flicker only occurs when the pagecontrol is visible once you scroll out of view of the `TPageControl` it stops. When the pagecontrol is resized so that the scroll arrows are no longer required to see all of the tabs then the flickering stops.

I'm fairly confident that the problem is caused by the scroll arrows causing some painting to occur because when I set the `TPageControl.MultiLine` to true then there is no flickering. Ideally I wouldn't want to use MultiLine tabs and hope someone can provide a solution.

**Information about form layout**

I have a (Personal Details) form which contains a number of `TSpeedButtons`, `TLabels`, `TEdits`, a `TImage` and so on. Many of these elements are inside of a `TScrollBox` and are grouped into sections using `TPanels`. The panels are set to `alTop` in the scrollbox and have autosize set to true but their height never changes.

I have tried setting all controls to have `DoubleBuffered` set to true where possible and `ParentBackground/Color = false` but sadly nothing works.

I had flickering issues before adding the PageControls and using David's quick hack answer here [TLabel and TGroupbox Captions Flicker on Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058745/tlabel-and-tgroupbox-captions-flicker-on-resize) I was able to improve the flickering when resizing the form. By extending TLabel and removing the background clearing from the Paint procedure, as recommended somewhere else, I was able to 99% remove the labels flickering when scrolling the ScrollBox but now I have a new flickering problem.

**---EDIT---**

Here is a link to a stripped down version of my form with the flickering occurring [flickering example](https://bitbucket.org/Exile322/pagecontrolflicker)

Personnel.DetailsForm.pas

```
unit Personnel.DetailsForm;

interface

uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
    Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, System.Actions,
    Vcl.ActnList, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.WinXCtrls, Vcl.Imaging.jpeg;

type
    TPersonnelDetailsForm = class(TForm)
        ScrollBox_Content: TScrollBox;
        panel_AddressDetails: TPanel;
        gpanel_Address: TGridPanel;
        edit_HomeMobilePhone: TEdit;
        edit_HomeTown: TEdit;
        edit_HomeStreet: TEdit;
        edit_HomePhone: TEdit;
        lbl_HomeStreet: TLabel;
        lbl_HomePhone: TLabel;
        lbl_MobilePhone: TLabel;
        lbl_HomeTown: TLabel;
        edit_HomeState: TEdit;
        edit_HomeEmail: TEdit;
        edit_HomeCountry: TEdit;
        edit_HomeFax: TEdit;
        lbl_HomeState: TLabel;
        lbl_Fax: TLabel;
        lbl_Email: TLabel;
        lbl_HomeCountry: TLabel;
        edit_HomePostCode: TEdit;
        lbl_HomePostCode: TLabel;
        panel_HomeAddressTitle: TPanel;
        panel_GeneralNotesDetails: TPanel;
        gpanel_GeneralNotesDetails_: TGridPanel;
        pageControl_GeneralNotes: TPageControl;
        procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
        procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
    private
        { Private declarations }
    public
        { Public declarations }
    end;

var
    PersonnelDetailsForm: TPersonnelDetailsForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
    System.Math,
    System.DateUtils,
    System.Threading,
    System.RegularExpressions,
    System.StrUtils,
    System.Contnrs,
    System.UITypes,
    System.Types,

    Winapi.Shellapi,

    Vcl.ExtDlgs;

procedure EnableComposited(WinControl: TWinControl);
var
    i: Integer;
    NewExStyle: DWORD;
begin
    NewExStyle := GetWindowLong(WinControl.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
    SetWindowLong(WinControl.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, NewExStyle);

    for i := 0 to WinControl.ControlCount - 1 do
        if WinControl.Controls[i] is TWinControl then
            EnableComposited(TWinControl(WinControl.Controls[i]));
end;

procedure TPersonnelDetailsForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
    // Close the form and make sure it frees itself
    Action := caFree; // Should allow it to free itself on close
    self.Release; // Sends a Release message to itself as backup
end;

procedure TPersonnelDetailsForm.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint;
    var Handled: Boolean);
var
    LTopLeft, LTopRight, LBottomLeft, LBottomRight: Integer;
    LPoint: TPoint;
begin
    Handled := true;

    // First you have to get the position of the control on screen
    // as MousePos coordinates are based on the screen positions.
    LPoint := self.ScrollBox_Content.ClientToScreen(Point(0, 0));
    LTopLeft := LPoint.X;
    LTopRight := LTopLeft + self.ScrollBox_Content.Width;
    LBottomLeft := LPoint.Y;
    LBottomRight := LBottomLeft + self.ScrollBox_Content.Width;

    if (MousePos.X >= LTopLeft) and (MousePos.X <= LTopRight) and (MousePos.Y >= LBottomLeft) and (MousePos.Y <= LBottomRight) then
    begin
        // If the mouse is inside the scrollbox coordinates,
        // scroll it by setting .VertScrollBar.Position.
        self.ScrollBox_Content.VertScrollBar.Position := self.ScrollBox_Content.VertScrollBar.Position - WheelDelta;
        Handled := true;
    end;

    if FindVCLWindow(MousePos) is TComboBox then
        Handled := true;
end;

procedure TPersonnelDetailsForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
    memo: TMemo;
    tabsheet: TTabSheet;
    ii: Integer;
begin
    for ii := 0 to 7 do
    begin
        memo := TMemo.Create(self);
        memo.Align := TAlign.alClient;
        memo.ReadOnly := true;
        memo.ScrollBars := TScrollStyle.ssVertical;
        memo.ParentColor := false;

        tabsheet := TTabSheet.Create(self);
        tabsheet.InsertControl(memo);
        tabsheet.PageControl := self.pageControl_GeneralNotes;
        tabsheet.Caption := 'A New TabSheet ' + IntToStr(ii);
        tabsheet.Tag := ii;

        memo.Text := 'A New Memo ' + IntToStr(ii);
    end;

    EnableComposited(self);

    self.ScrollBox_Content.ScrollInView(self.panel_AddressDetails);
    self.Invalidate;
end;

end.
```

Personnel.DetailsForm.dfm

```
object PersonnelDetailsForm: TPersonnelDetailsForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Personnel Details Form'
  ClientHeight = 371
  ClientWidth = 800
  Color = clBtnFace
  DoubleBuffered = True
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -13
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnClose = FormClose
  OnMouseWheel = FormMouseWheel
  OnShow = FormShow
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 17
  object ScrollBox_Content: TScrollBox
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 800
    Height = 371
    VertScrollBar.Smooth = True
    VertScrollBar.Tracking = True
    Align = alClient
    TabOrder = 0
    object panel_AddressDetails: TPanel
      Tag = 101
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Width = 796
      Height = 174
      Align = alTop
      Padding.Left = 5
      Padding.Top = 5
      Padding.Right = 5
      Padding.Bottom = 5
      ParentBackground = False
      TabOrder = 0
      object gpanel_Address: TGridPanel
        Left = 6
        Top = 30
        Width = 784
        Height = 138
        Align = alClient
        BevelOuter = bvNone
        ColumnCollection = <
          item
            SizeStyle = ssAbsolute
            Value = 105.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Value = 50.000762951094850000
          end
          item
            SizeStyle = ssAbsolute
            Value = 105.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            Value = 49.999237048905160000
          end>
        ControlCollection = <
          item
            Column = 3
            Control = edit_HomeMobilePhone
            Row = 1
          end
          item
            Column = 1
            Control = edit_HomeTown
            Row = 1
          end
          item
            Column = 1
            Control = edit_HomeStreet
            Row = 0
          end
          item
            Column = 3
            Control = edit_HomePhone
            Row = 0
          end
          item
            Column = 0
            Control = lbl_HomeStreet
            Row = 0
          end
          item
            Column = 2
            Control = lbl_HomePhone
            Row = 0
          end
          item
            Column = 2
            Control = lbl_MobilePhone
            Row = 1
          end
          item
            Column = 0
            Control = lbl_HomeTown
            Row = 1
          end
          item
            Column = 1
            Control = edit_HomeState
            Row = 2
          end
          item
            Column = 3
            Control = edit_HomeEmail
            Row = 2
          end
          item
            Column = 1
            Control = edit_HomeCountry
            Row = 3
          end
          item
            Column = 3
            Control = edit_HomeFax
            Row = 3
          end
          item
            Column = 0
            Control = lbl_HomeState
            Row = 2
          end
          item
            Column = 2
            Control = lbl_Fax
            Row = 3
          end
          item
            Column = 2
            Control = lbl_Email
            Row = 2
          end
          item
            Column = 0
            Control = lbl_HomeCountry
            Row = 3
          end
          item
            Column = 1
            Control = edit_HomePostCode
            Row = 4
          end
          item
            Column = 0
            Control = lbl_HomePostCode
            Row = 4
          end>
        Padding.Left = 1
        Padding.Top = 1
        Padding.Right = 1
        Padding.Bottom = 1
        RowCollection = <
          item
            SizeStyle = ssAbsolute
            Value = 27.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            SizeStyle = ssAbsolute
            Value = 27.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            SizeStyle = ssAbsolute
            Value = 27.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            SizeStyle = ssAbsolute
            Value = 27.000000000000000000
          end
          item
            SizeStyle = ssAbsolute
            Value = 27.000000000000000000
          end>
        TabOrder = 0
        object edit_HomeMobilePhone: TEdit
          Left = 498
          Top = 29
          Width = 284
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          BevelInner = bvNone
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          TabOrder = 6
          Text = 'Mobile Phone'
        end
        object edit_HomeTown: TEdit
          Left = 107
          Top = 29
          Width = 284
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          BevelInner = bvNone
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          TabOrder = 1
          Text = 'Home Town'
        end
        object edit_HomeStreet: TEdit
          Left = 107
          Top = 2
          Width = 284
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          BevelInner = bvNone
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          TabOrder = 0
          Text = 'Home Street'
        end
        object edit_HomePhone: TEdit
          Left = 498
          Top = 2
          Width = 284
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          BevelInner = bvNone
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          TabOrder = 5
          Text = 'Home Phone'
        end
        object lbl_HomeStreet: TLabel
          Left = 2
          Top = 2
          Width = 103
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          Alignment = taRightJustify
          Caption = 'Street: '
          Color = clBtnFace
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clWindowText
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
          Font.Style = [fsBold]
          ParentColor = False
          ParentFont = False
          Transparent = True
          Layout = tlCenter
          ExplicitLeft = 61
          ExplicitWidth = 44
          ExplicitHeight = 17
        end
        object lbl_HomePhone: TLabel
          Left = 393
          Top = 2
          Width = 103
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          Alignment = taRightJustify
          Caption = 'Home Phone: '
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clWindowText
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
          Font.Style = [fsBold]
          ParentFont = False
          Layout = tlCenter
          ExplicitLeft = 408
          ExplicitWidth = 88
          ExplicitHeight = 17
        end
        object lbl_MobilePhone: TLabel
          Left = 393
          Top = 29
          Width = 103
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          Alignment = taRightJustify
          Caption = 'Mobile Phone: '
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clWindowText
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
          Font.Style = [fsBold]
          ParentFont = False
          Layout = tlCenter
          ExplicitLeft = 402
          ExplicitWidth = 94
          ExplicitHeight = 17
        end
        object lbl_HomeTown: TLabel
          Left = 2
          Top = 29
          Width = 103
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          Alignment = taRightJustify
          Caption = 'Town: '
          Color = clBtnFace
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clWindowText
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
          Font.Style = [fsBold]
          ParentColor = False
          ParentFont = False
          Transparent = True
          Layout = tlCenter
          ExplicitLeft = 64
          ExplicitWidth = 41
          ExplicitHeight = 17
        end
        object edit_HomeState: TEdit
          Left = 107
          Top = 56
          Width = 284
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          BevelInner = bvNone
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          TabOrder = 2
          Text = 'Home State'
        end
        object edit_HomeEmail: TEdit
          Left = 498
          Top = 56
          Width = 284
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          BevelInner = bvNone
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          TabOrder = 7
          Text = 'Home Email'
        end
        object edit_HomeCountry: TEdit
          Left = 107
          Top = 83
          Width = 284
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          BevelInner = bvNone
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          TabOrder = 3
          Text = 'Home Country'
        end
        object edit_HomeFax: TEdit
          Left = 498
          Top = 83
          Width = 284
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          BevelInner = bvNone
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          TabOrder = 8
          Text = 'Home Fax'
        end
        object lbl_HomeState: TLabel
          Left = 2
          Top = 56
          Width = 103
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          Alignment = taRightJustify
          Caption = 'State: '
          Color = clBtnFace
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clWindowText
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
          Font.Style = [fsBold]
          ParentColor = False
          ParentFont = False
          Transparent = True
          Layout = tlCenter
          ExplicitLeft = 66
          ExplicitWidth = 39
          ExplicitHeight = 17
        end
        object lbl_Fax: TLabel
          Left = 393
          Top = 83
          Width = 103
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          Alignment = taRightJustify
          Caption = 'Fax: '
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clWindowText
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
          Font.Style = [fsBold]
          ParentFont = False
          Layout = tlCenter
          ExplicitLeft = 467
          ExplicitWidth = 29
          ExplicitHeight = 17
        end
        object lbl_Email: TLabel
          Left = 393
          Top = 56
          Width = 103
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          Alignment = taRightJustify
          Caption = 'Email: '
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clWindowText
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
          Font.Style = [fsBold]
          ParentFont = False
          Layout = tlCenter
          ExplicitLeft = 454
          ExplicitWidth = 42
          ExplicitHeight = 17
        end
        object lbl_HomeCountry: TLabel
          Left = 2
          Top = 83
          Width = 103
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          Alignment = taRightJustify
          Caption = 'Country: '
          Color = clBtnFace
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clWindowText
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
          Font.Style = [fsBold]
          ParentColor = False
          ParentFont = False
          Transparent = True
          Layout = tlCenter
          ExplicitLeft = 47
          ExplicitWidth = 58
          ExplicitHeight = 17
        end
        object edit_HomePostCode: TEdit
          Left = 107
          Top = 110
          Width = 284
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          BevelInner = bvNone
          BevelOuter = bvNone
          TabOrder = 4
          Text = 'Home Post Code'
        end
        object lbl_HomePostCode: TLabel
          Left = 2
          Top = 110
          Width = 103
          Height = 25
          Align = alClient
          Alignment = taRightJustify
          Caption = 'Post Code: '
          Color = clBtnFace
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clWindowText
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
          Font.Style = [fsBold]
          ParentColor = False
          ParentFont = False
          Transparent = True
          Layout = tlCenter
          ExplicitLeft = 35
          ExplicitWidth = 70
          ExplicitHeight = 17
        end
      end
      object panel_HomeAddressTitle: TPanel
        Left = 6
        Top = 6
        Width = 784
        Height = 24
        Align = alTop
        Alignment = taLeftJustify
        BevelOuter = bvNone
        Caption = ' Home Address '
        Color = clMedGray
        Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
        Font.Color = clWindowText
        Font.Height = -13
        Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
        Font.Style = [fsBold, fsUnderline]
        ParentBackground = False
        ParentFont = False
        TabOrder = 1
      end
    end
    object panel_GeneralNotesDetails: TPanel
      Tag = 303
      Left = 0
      Top = 174
      Width = 796
      Height = 172
      Align = alTop
      AutoSize = True
      Padding.Left = 5
      Padding.Top = 5
      Padding.Right = 5
      Padding.Bottom = 5
      ParentBackground = False
      TabOrder = 1
      object gpanel_GeneralNotesDetails_: TGridPanel
        Left = 6
        Top = 6
        Width = 784
        Height = 160
        Align = alTop
        BevelOuter = bvNone
        ColumnCollection = <
          item
            Value = 100.000000000000000000
          end>
        ControlCollection = <
          item
            Column = 0
            Control = pageControl_GeneralNotes
            Row = 0
          end>
        Padding.Left = 1
        Padding.Top = 1
        Padding.Right = 1
        Padding.Bottom = 1
        RowCollection = <
          item
            SizeStyle = ssAbsolute
            Value = 160.000000000000000000
          end>
        TabOrder = 0
        object pageControl_GeneralNotes: TPageControl
          Left = 2
          Top = 2
          Width = 780
          Height = 158
          Align = alClient
          TabOrder = 0
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How can we reproduce this issue?

Comment: I'll try to create an example project for you

Comment: @KenWhite I have created an example project showing the problem

Comment: It's not in your question here, so it doesn't exist. We're not going elsewhere to get the code. If that external site disappears, so does the code, and then the question has no value to future readers here. The relevant information needs to be **here**, in the question itself.

Comment: @KenWhite you have a great point and I have added a very stripped down version of the dfm and pas to the question which will demonstrate the flickering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was caused by the [quick hack David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8060672/49925) answered to [TLabel and TGroupbox Captions Flicker on Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058745/tlabel-and-tgroupbox-captions-flicker-on-resize) after I removed that the mad flickering when the `TPageControl` tab scroll buttons were visible went away. So now I'll have to look at his more in-depth solution and see if that can help with some of the flickering I was seeing before.